# Use awk to pad date and time formats

Tags: text-processing, awk

I would like to use `awk` to pad the date and time fields in my report. Here is my current .csv that is actually tab delimited.

```
AA  9/7/2014 2:30:38 PM     AA0000011111    08 Y    A       Jane, Doe
AA  9/7/2014 11:30:31 AM     AA0000011112    09 Y    B       John, Doe
AA  9/7/2014 7:30:45 AM     AA0000011113    20 Y    A       Jane, Doe A
AA  9/8/2014 11:01:14 AM    AA0000011114    30 Y    A       John, Doe A
AA  9/8/2014 2:30:46 PM     7BD1111111115   40 Y    B       Jane, Doe A
AA  9/8/2014 2:31:00 PM     AA0000011116    50 Y    A       John, Doe A
AA  9/8/2014 7:30:53 AM     AA0000011117    60 Y    B       Jane, Doe
AA  9/9/2014 7:30:27 AM     AA0000011118    70 Y    A       John, Doe A
AA  9/9/2014 7:30:41 AM     AA0000011119    80 Y    B       Jane, Doe
AA  9/9/2014 7:30:55 AM     AA0000011110    90 Y    A       John, Doe
AA  9/14/2014 7:30:55 AM     AA0000011111    80 Y    A       Jane, Doe A
AA  11/11/2014 7:30:55 AM     AA0000011112    80 Y    A       John, Doe A
```

I would like to pad all the dates and times to make them easier to read and sort. Like this:

```
AA  09/07/2014 02:30:38 PM     AA0000011111    08 Y    A       Jane, Doe
AA  09/07/2014 11:30:31 AM     AA0000011112    09 Y    B       John, Doe
AA  09/07/2014 07:30:45 AM     AA0000011113    20 Y    A       Jane, Doe A
AA  09/08/2014 11:01:14 AM     AA0000011114    30 Y    A       John, Doe A
AA  09/08/2014 02:30:46 PM     7BD1111111115   40 Y    B       Jane, Doe A
AA  09/08/2014 02:31:00 PM     AA0000011116    50 Y    A       John, Doe A
AA  09/08/2014 07:30:53 AM     AA0000011117    60 Y    B       Jane, Doe
AA  09/09/2014 07:30:27 AM     AA0000011118    70 Y    A       John, Doe A
AA  09/09/2014 07:30:41 AM     AA0000011119    80 Y    B       Jane, Doe
AA  09/09/2014 07:30:55 AM     AA0000011110    90 Y    A       John, Doe
AA  09/14/2014 07:30:55 AM     AA0000011111    80 Y    A       Jane, Doe A
AA  11/11/2014 07:30:55 AM     AA0000011112    80 Y    A       John, Doe
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have the GNU implementation of `awk` or `mawk` [1.3.4-20121129 or newer](http://invisible-island.net/mawk/CHANGES.html#t20121129), try:

```
$ awk '
{
    split($2,a,"/");
    split($3,b,":");
    split(strftime("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S",mktime(a[3]" "a[1]" "a[2]" "b[1]" "b[2]" "b[3])),c);
    $2 = c[1];
    $3 = c[2];
    print;
}
' file
AA 09/07/2014 02:30:38 PM AA0000011111 08 Y A Jane, Doe
AA 09/07/2014 11:30:31 AM AA0000011112 09 Y B John, Doe
AA 09/07/2014 07:30:45 AM AA0000011113 20 Y A Jane, Doe A
AA 09/08/2014 11:01:14 AM AA0000011114 30 Y A John, Doe A
AA 09/08/2014 02:30:46 PM 7BD1111111115 40 Y B Jane, Doe A
AA 09/08/2014 02:31:00 PM AA0000011116 50 Y A John, Doe A
AA 09/08/2014 07:30:53 AM AA0000011117 60 Y B Jane, Doe
AA 09/09/2014 07:30:27 AM AA0000011118 70 Y A John, Doe A
AA 09/09/2014 07:30:41 AM AA0000011119 80 Y B Jane, Doe
AA 09/09/2014 07:30:55 AM AA0000011110 90 Y A John, Doe
AA 09/14/2014 07:30:55 AM AA0000011111 80 Y A Jane, Doe A
AA 11/11/2014 07:30:55 AM AA0000011112 80 Y A John, Doe A
```

**Explanation**

- We split the date string, save to array `a`
- We split the time string, save to array `b`
- The next part, we use `strftime` and `mktime` function to get the desired result.

  - `mktime(a[3]" "a[1]" "a[2]" "b[1]" "b[2]" "b[3])` get the string in format `Year Month Day Hour Min Sec` to convert time to seconds since epoch.
  - `strftime` get the format `"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S"` and the time procedured by `mktime`, create the desired result for us.
- We split the result, save in array `c`, assign back to `$2`, `$3` and print the output.

**NOTE**

- [gawk Time Functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Time-Functions.html)

Comment: This works, but unfortunately it's so far beyond my understanding of AWK, that I have a hard time following the logic. Would you mind breaking it down for me.

Comment: @user72055: Added explanation.

Comment: While you're at it, you could reorder the dates to 2014-09-14 which is less ambiguous and helps with sorting.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: Newest version of `mawk` support `mktime` and `strftime`, see: http://invisible-island.net/mawk/manpage/mawk.txt

Answer (score 3):

You specify the width and zero padding using printf modifiers in awk:

```
$ awk -F'[/:]| +' '{ printf "%s %02d/%02d/%02d %02d:%02d:%02d %s %-13s %s %s %s %s %s %s\n",
              $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11, $12, $13, $14, $15 } ' input_file
AA 09/07/2014 02:30:38 PM  AA0000011111  08 Y A Jane, Doe 
AA 09/07/2014 11:30:31 AM  AA0000011112  09 Y B John, Doe 
AA 09/07/2014 07:30:45 AM  AA0000011113  20 Y A Jane, Doe A
AA 09/08/2014 11:01:14 AM  AA0000011114  30 Y A John, Doe A
AA 09/08/2014 02:30:46 PM  7BD1111111115 40 Y B Jane, Doe A
AA 09/08/2014 02:31:00 PM  AA0000011116  50 Y A John, Doe A
AA 09/08/2014 07:30:53 AM  AA0000011117  60 Y B Jane, Doe 
AA 09/09/2014 07:30:27 AM  AA0000011118  70 Y A John, Doe A
AA 09/09/2014 07:30:41 AM  AA0000011119  80 Y B Jane, Doe 
AA 09/09/2014 07:30:55 AM  AA0000011110  90 Y A John, Doe 
AA 09/14/2014 07:30:55 AM  AA0000011111  80 Y A Jane, Doe A
AA 11/11/2014 07:30:55 AM  AA0000011112  80 Y A John, Doe A
```

Comment: I understand and like this solution, but without padding the dates and times, my sort function will put 11/11/2014 before 1/11/2014 and 9/14/2014.

Comment: @user72055, over-read the zero-padding requirement in your question the first time - I've changed the answer such that dates/times are now zero padded.

Comment: I like this code. It is straight forward and easy for me to comprehend at my skill level. Thank you!

Comment: @user72055 - You mention sorting - you want the date elements to be presented as YYYY/MM/DD (change argument order to $4, $3, $2). Then you can use "sort -n" to perform numeric sort, respecting years and months.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use `sed`:

```
sed -e :1 -e 's|^\([^:]*[ /]\)\([0-9][/:]\)|\10\2|;t1'
```

Inserts a 0 before any single digit in between a space or `/` and `/` or `:` in the part leading to the first `:`.

Comment: This worked very well. Thank you for the alternative.